# Can the SDK version 10 function run on a device with a system version of 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I create a button to call someone , and i used to code like this :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"123"];
```

But now i noticed this function has a warning , in iOS10 Apple provides a new function to instead it , here it is :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"123"] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

                }];
```

It has a parameter so i can get if the user clicks the **confirm** button.

But i am not sure about this function if there will be any error with a device has system version 8;

English is not my native language , please forgive my grammatical mistakes , i had search on google but get nothing useful .
Any ideas ? 

Very thankful !

Chang Liu.

Comment: Well, when something in Apple APIs changes, first it becomes `deprecated` — current API still supports old feature (and may stay in this state for few versions), but it's not approved way to do things now, and you should think about updating your code, then it becomes `obsolete` when it's no longer available and you no longer able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to be concerned; if you attempt to call an iOS 10 method on an earlier version of iOS you will get a runtime "does not respond to selector" exception.  You have a few options:

1. Use the deprecated method; it will continue to work for now, but will no longer be supported at some future version of iOS, so you will have to deal with it eventually.
2. Target only newer versions of iOS; iOS users tend to upgrade and targeting iOS 9.x + will cover the vast majority of iOS users.  The method in this case is iOS 10 only and you may not wish to cut off iOS 9 (or even iOS 8 ) users at this point
3. Check the version of iOS at runtime and invoke the appropriate method:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 10.0) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"123"];
} else {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"123"] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

            }];
}
```

Comment: thank you very much , I am hesitant to use this approach, and now it seems that this is right.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the Base SDK version and iOS version,then use differnt API,like this:

```
#if  __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > __IPHONE_9_3
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue > 10.0f) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"123"] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

        }];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"123"]];
    }
#else
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"123"]];
#endif
```